# Matlab neural network (ANN) csv file

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know of a good place to get a csv spreadsheet of some data to make a neural network with? Its for an assignment to do with matlab.

I need it to be something very similar to the crabdata file that comes with matlab.

I have no actual idea on what the csv would be about, just something in the format of:
couple of columbs of data and final result that can be mapped to 0 or 1.

Comment: Could you explain the assignment a little more detailed? What do you want to use the CSV file for? To train the ANN?

Comment: Our teacher is pretty bad, he expects us to make a neural network, but he barely taught us anything. Just handed out sheets of maths formulas. Yes its to train the ANN. I understand the crab data, so I could make something similar, but I want to use something either than crab data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to look in the folder where the `crab_dataset.mat` data file exists? There appear to be **a lot** of other demo data sets there. Here's a short lesson in finding where things are in MATLAB...

The function [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) will tell you the path to a given function or file:

```
>> filePath = which('crab_dataset.mat')

filePath =

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet\nndemos\nndatasets\crab_dataset.mat
```

If you want just the path to the directory without the file name, you can use the function [FILEPARTS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html):

```
>> directoryPath = fileparts(filePath)

directoryPath =

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\nnet\nndemos\nndatasets
```

And if you want to look at the contents of a directory, you can use the function [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html):

```
>> dir(directoryPath)

.                          glass_dataset.mat          simpleclass_dataset.m      
..                         house_dataset.m            simpleclass_dataset.mat    
Contents.m                 house_dataset.mat          simplecluster_create.m     
abalone_dataset.m          ice_dataset.m              simplecluster_dataset.m    
abalone_dataset.mat        ice_dataset.mat            simplecluster_dataset.mat  
bodyfat_dataset.m          iris_dataset.m             simplefit_create.m         
bodyfat_dataset.mat        iris_dataset.mat           simplefit_dataset.m        
building_dataset.m         laser_dataset.m            simplefit_dataset.mat      
building_dataset.mat       laser_dataset.mat          simplenar_dataset.m        
cancer_dataset.m           maglev_dataset.m           simplenar_dataset.mat      
cancer_dataset.mat         maglev_dataset.mat         simplenarx_dataset.m       
chemical_dataset.m         oil_dataset.m              simplenarx_dataset.mat     
chemical_dataset.mat       oil_dataset.mat            simpleseries_dataset.m     
chickenpox_dataset.m       ph_dataset.m               simpleseries_dataset.mat   
chickenpox_dataset.mat     ph_dataset.mat             solar_dataset.m            
cho_dataset.m              pollution_dataset.m        solar_dataset.mat          
cho_dataset.mat            pollution_dataset.mat      thyroid_dataset.m          
crab_dataset.m             refmodel_dataset.m         thyroid_dataset.mat        
crab_dataset.mat           refmodel_dataset.mat       valve_dataset.m            
engine_dataset.m           river_dataset.m            valve_dataset.mat          
engine_dataset.mat         river_dataset.mat          wine_dataset.m             
exchanger_dataset.m        robotarm_dataset.m         wine_dataset.mat           
exchanger_dataset.mat      robotarm_dataset.mat       
glass_dataset.m            simpleclass_create.m
```

Look at all those MAT files! I'm sure you could find one of them that would be good for training your neural network.